# Weird gibberish characters appearing on bottom of Drupal 7 pages

Tags: 7, debugging

What are some reasons to why there would be weird gibberish characters appearing on the bottom of a Drupal 7 site? I work in a linux environment, but sometimes I copy the files over from windows. I'm not sure if that is the culprit, but how would one even debug something like this?

[image]

Comment: This almost looks like the contents of an image or video file are sent to the screen in plain text. What is your `dialog-playlist-container` supposed to contain? Is it some misbehaving lightbox? Try to disable any module that provides a pop-up modal that is supposed to contain images. If this only happens occasionally, perhaps the image is corrupted? This is not normal Drupal behavior and without more details there is unfortunately not much we can do.

Comment: I believe this is the result of some resource compression issue; what you're seeing is the embedding of some gzipped resource. I couldn't find a good resource on the topic, but you should look at cache clearing and investigating your Apache/PHP/Drupal compression setting and how that might be affected by what you're doing.

Comment: does switching to a Drupal 7 default theme change anything?

Comment: @ShawnConn I believe you are right. Perhaps disabling page compresson can fix this, $conf['page_compression'] = FALSE; in settings.php

Comment: it only pops up sometimes. i'll give those a try, but for something random like this its hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Since these characters appearing within certain section of the website, you need to identify the source of it and which rendering element is responsible for it (either template file or some function).

The easiest way would be to track it down by enabling `theme_debug` variable in your settings file which enable you to debug the output of the rendering engine.

So please add this line into your settings file:

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

then refresh the page and check the source code to see which rendering element is outputting this.

---

For more advanced solution, use PHP debugger such as [`phpdbg`](http://phpdbg.com/) (in PHP >=5.6 core) or [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/) (which allows you to generate a trace file and find the source of the problem). Here is sample [`xdebug.ini`](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/conf/php/xdebug.ini) config, so in your scenario you just need to enable `xdebug.auto_trace`, generate a trace file for single page load, then disable the setting (since it hugely impacts the overall performance). Then open a generated trace file, look for gibberish where they've started to appear and find out which code is generating it.

Comment: is phpdbg better than xdebug without needing to recompile php with xdebug?

Comment: For XDebug, you don't need to recompile your PHP, you just need to install PHP module. In most of systems it's just one-liner to install XDebug (like `brew install php5-xdebug` on Mac or `sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug` on Linux).

Comment: Another thing i just read was that xdebug causes a performance hit while phpdbg doesnt. Is this true from your experience? thx

Comment: It's true, but I haven't used phpdbg to tell the difference. Mainly I'm using XDebug. If you don't have `auto_trace`/`profiler_enable` enabled by default, the performance difference is really small. Having stacktraces shown on errors (`xdebug.default_enable`) gives more benefits in terms of troubleshooting issues which may overcome the actual speed difference, especially when you're using just for your local/dev environment.